# What happens if you mount a SD card on a folder that is not empty?

Tags: mount

I have to mount a SD card to a folder (designated by rules)
(Plus there is no more space in the device to create another folder)

What happens if I mount the SD card on that folder? (now it has a subfolder by another user)

When mounting we do

```
mount  <SD card> /afolder
```

normally I have no problem

but now /afolder contains another subfolder

```
ls /afolder
someuserfolder
```

Comment: Question is not clear. What folder has no space? What version of Ubuntu? Who made these rules?

Comment: @David I will edit

Answer (score 2):

The contents of that folder will become inaccessible, until the drive is unmounted.

This may lead to unexpected behaviour. Suppose I backup my files to `/mnt/backups` but the backup drive is not mounted. The files will be copied to the `/` partition, in the folder `/mnt/backups` instead of to the backup drive. When I subsequently mount the backup drive, the backed up files are not there. Meanwhile, the files do take up space on the `/` partition.

So care needs to be taken, in backup procedures, that the target drive is actually mounted, at the time of the backup. If not mounted, abort the backup.

Comment: What backup? I think you wandered in your example.